# Which characters are Invalid (unless encoded) in an XML attribute?

Tags: xml, xml-serialization

I can't believe I can't find this information easily accessible, so:

1) Which characters cannot be incorporated in an XML attribute without entity-encoding them?

Obviously, you need to encode quotes. What about `<` and `>`? What else?

2) Where exactly is the official list?

Answer (score 60):

Here is the definition of [what is allowed in an attribute value](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-AttValue).

```
'"' ([^<&"] | Reference)* '"'  |  "'" ([^<&'] | Reference)* "'"
```

So, you can't have:

- the same character that opens/closes the attribute value (*either* `'` or `"`)
- a naked ampersand (`&` must be `&amp;`)
- a left angle bracket (`<` must be `&lt;`)

You should also not being using any [characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Char) that are outright not legal anywhere in an XML document (such as form feeds, etc).

Comment: It is good to avoid the two-character string `--` as well. Otherwise, you run into trouble if you want to wrap that content in a comment. (Since `--` is not legal inside a comment.)

Answer (score 6):

As per the (2) [current recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/), specifically regarding [character data and Markup](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#syntax), they are (1) the ampersand (&), left angle bracket (<), right angle bracket (>) and both single-quote (') and double-quote (").

Comment: I agree on the section of the spec document. However, not all of those attributes "must" be escaped. Can you edit to clarify?

Comment: -1 There is no requirement to escape `>`, nor the `'` or `"` (that is not being used to delimit the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

See [2.2 Characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204/#charsets) in ["Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Third Edition)"](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204/).

Note that, at least with .NET, if you are using the XML APIs to work with XML, then you won't have to worry about this. It's the reason not to treat XML as being text.

Comment: I agree on the document location, but I don't think that that specific section is the correct place to look at. That section lists the valid characters allowed in the "text stream", if you will. About .NET and libraries, I couldn't agree more -- but in this particular case I need to edit an existing text file that contains XML.

Comment: So, why not use the XML APIs to process that text file?

Comment: Better is to use the current version of the documents: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/