# Is it valid to put div tags in title="" field

Tags: html, tooltip

Is this valid for a tooltip? For some reason I thought it wasn't valid to add divs within the title field.

```
<div class="graph_item tooltip" title="
    <div id='tooltip_inner_container'>
    <div id='title'>Ready Set Cook!</div>
        <strong>250 HEALTHY POINTS</strong>
            The Goal of Ready, Set, Cook! is to cook and log at least 1 recipe per week for 8 weeks. If you complete this challenge, You will 
             become eligible for prizes.<br /><br />
            Registration:
            May 7 - May 14<br />
            Duration: May 15 - June 6
    </div>
" style="width:100%; height:58px; left:0%; top:0%; background-color:#0073ad; background-image:url(images/a.jpg);">
```

Comment: why shouldn't it be allowed?

Comment: You can do it but don't expect the html to render in the little popup that shows the title text.

Comment: It won't do what you probably want it to — it won't display as a `div`. It'll just have that whole block as text. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77rah/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which characters are Invalid (unless encoded) in an XML attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866706/which-characters-are-invalid-unless-encoded-in-an-xml-attribute)

Comment: If you're trying to show that `div` you can use `onmouseover`.

Answer (score 1):

Not a valid XML either, you should never put nodes inside an attribute.

i would suggest to use an html like:

```
<div class="graph_item has-tooltip"  style="width:100%; height:58px; left:0%; top:0%;    background-color:#0073ad; background-image:url(images/a.jpg);">
  <div class="tooltip" id='tooltip_inner_container'>
    <div id='title'>Ready Set Cook!</div>
        <strong>250 HEALTHY POINTS</strong>
            The Goal of Ready, Set, Cook! is to cook and log at least 1 recipe per week for 8 weeks. If you complete this challenge, You will 
             become eligible for prizes.<br /><br />
            Registration:
            May 7 - May 14<br />
            Duration: May 15 - June 6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

as css:
.has-tooltip .tooltip{ display: none; }
.has-tooltip .tooltip:hover{ display: block; }

Comment: It's a normal string? just with a few < and >

Comment: If you're using the jquery tooltip though, it's fine? Or is it best to just use text in the title field?

Comment: attributes are not a valid xml nodes container, you can't predict how the browsers would handle it, I would use a jquery tooltip solution instead if more complex text is required as tooltip

Comment: What @bwoebi is saying is that while it doesn't achieve what OP wants, it **is** valid HTML.

Comment: Yes it is the jquery tooltip

Comment: @Edorka - XML is irrelevant here. Also, ever heard of the [`srcdoc`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-srcdoc) attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your HTML is valid (if you close the `div`, of course).

However, the content of this `title` attribute is *not* (and can not be) HTML. It’s text.

> [image]

Comment: @B--rian: This is *not* an image of code, but an image of text where the text contains what looks like to be, but is not, code. That’s the whole point of the answer and the image: to show that HTML code in the `title` attribute does not get interpreted as HTML, but as text.