# IIS Redirect with More than 1 Parameter

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-redirect

When I try redirect to another page with more than 1 parameter in querystring I get an error.

This works:

```
<rule name="t6" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^test.html$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="mypage.aspx?param=1" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<rule name="t6" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^test.html$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="mypage.aspx?param=1&param2=2" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Can you figure what's happening?

Thanks,

Armando

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace instances of

```
&
```

with

```
&amp;
```

so your url parameter becomes

```
url="mypage.aspx?param=1&amp;param2=2"
```

this is an encoding requirement of xml.

ref: [Which characters are Invalid (unless encoded) in an XML attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866706/which-characters-are-invalid-unless-encoded-in-an-xml-attribute)