# Entity '&' not defined on the xml file

Tags: xml

***a.xml***

```
 <text name="PdmFLJNotReceived" value="FL&&J Not Received" />
```

I need to show the text as `FL&J Not Received`.But when I use it like above then
It gives the error `Entity '&' not defined`. Could you tell me how to correct the error ? Thanks.

Comment: A 5 seconds Google search would tell you how to solve this. And how is this C#-related?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which characters are Invalid (unless encoded) in an XML attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866706/which-characters-are-invalid-unless-encoded-in-an-xml-attribute)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&` is not a valid Xml character by itself. Use `&amp;` for `&`

Answer (score 1):

Use the escaped version, e.g:

`&amp;` or `&#38;`

[More](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php)

Or use a [CDATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256076(v=vs.110).aspx) section  e.g:

```
<![CDATA[FL&&J Not Received]]>
```