# Why adding special characters after a string inside XAML Content attribute works

Tags: xml, xaml

Some special characters require encoding [as explained in here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970677(v=vs.110).aspx)

However, this does not explain why they work if added after a string:

**Works**:

```
<Button Content="Forward>>" />
```

**Does not work**:

```
<Button Content="<<Back" />
```

*Explain why it works in the first case*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a question of valid XML, and the issue is related to the character you're attempting to use, not the position.

**Works:**

```
<Button Content=">>Back" />
```

**Does not work:**

```
<Button Content="Forward<<" />
```

I believe the only characters you aren't allowed to use are the same as those rejected by [XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/866894/3194005).

- the same character that opens/closes the attribute value (either `'` or `"`)
- a naked ampersand (`&` must be `&amp;`)
- a left angle bracket (`<` must be `&lt;`)